# Почему нужен редирект после отправки post запроса?

Tags: php, symfony2

В общем суть проблемы такова, на странице находятся 3 формы на обновление данных, одна на профиль пользователя, вторя на ресет пароля 3-я на на изменение email. Я сделал отправку форм в контроллер и соответственно редирект на эту же страницу. Руководитель проекта сказал что редиректы нужно убрать, мол люди не жмут F5, а повторные редиректы будут нагружать сервер. Может я что то не понимаю но я раньше всегда после отправки POST запроса делал редиректы. Предложение сделать все формы через ajax  отвергнуто. В общем как можно обосновать грамотно что редирект нужен или я ошибаюсь?

В общем задал похожий вопрос на английском stackoverflow там дали интересную ссылочку, прикрепляю http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post

Comment: Вот так и опровергнуть: 1) Люди *жмут* reload 2) Ещё они жмут кнопку "назад" 3) Загрузка сервера редиректом? Меняйте  руководителя.

Comment: @PinkTux он наш senior и фактически наниматель, скорее уволят меня =)

Comment: вы можете отправлять данные на этот же контроллер ( который рендерит страницу с формами).Приняли данные и сразу нарисовали "финальную,желаемую" страницу. Редирект не нужен, аякс не используется. условия выполнены?

Comment: Вы используете Symfony Form'ы или нет?

Comment: Командир сказал бурундук птичка - значит полетит. Сказал не жмут - значит не жмут. Делайте как говорит насяльника

Comment: @AmsTaFFix да это symfony form type, точнее 2 формы такие 3-я просто обычная

Comment: удалил свой ответ в связи с тем, что недопонял вопроса. Да редирект нужен, можете указать ему на документацию в Symfony: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions

Comment: @AmsTaFFix Форма на обновление данных, там где добавление, редиректы разрешают использовать =) стоит отметить что из-за 3-х форм и обработки их в 1-м контроллере редиректов было достаточно много, при обработке ошибок различных, например не совпадение пароля текущего.

Comment: да-да, мы сами редиректим после удачной обработки запроса, повторюсь - неправильно понял сути вопроса :(

Comment: а откуда там было много редиректов? у вас их там должно быть около 3

Comment: @AmsTaFFix думаю через месяц прилетит wtf  where is redirect? =)

Comment: скорее всего так и будет

Comment: @AmsTaFFix 3 минимум, на поиске дубликата email и обработке ошибок в общем точно ещё штучки 2 где то было +-1

Comment: А можете кодом дополнить вопрос, мне интересно откуда еще редиректы появились. Просто у нас одна форма == один редирект

Answer (score 3):

Редирект не нагружает сервер, по факту получается такая схема:

1) Обработка POST'a

2) REDIRECT

3) Ответ клиенту

Ваш тим.лид предлагает 1-3, что он сэкономит? если у вас проект что при каждом обращении клиента там жесть что происходит, тогда нужно смотреть проект чтобы такого не было...

P.S. А по факту, если +1 обращение к серверу - это так критично, то это фигня а не сервер)))

Comment: @AmsTaFFix если фреймворк настолько тяжел, что даже инициализация требует заметного количества ресурсов, то стоит задуматься о том чтобы сменить фреймворк

Comment: по поводу вопроса - я его неправильно понял и в данном конкретном случае редирект сделать стоит, независимо от нагрузки на сервер. Обсуждение фреймворков - это холивар, в котором я участвовать не хочу :)